# Styling Wordpress Gallery to handle Landscape and Portrait images differently

Tags: wordpress, html, gallery, figure

I am trying to style my Wordpress galleries to display in a continuous vertical column but display two vertical (portrait orientation) photos side-by-side at 50%.

This should be fairly straightforward as Wordpress already adds a class to the photos based on their orientation, `.portrait` and `.landscape`, and then adding a simple `float` or `inline-block` to it.

The problem seems to be in the `figure` tag staying at 100% width and not being affected by `inline-block` styling at all. Perhaps one of you can figure out what I'm overlooking here either using this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/tylorreimer/u4sx6gst/) or the live site (https://thereimers.co/grand-canyon/).

[image: How the gallery should look]

Answer (score 0):

```
.gallery-item{
    display: contents;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Please add some explanation to your code, so everyone looking for this answer can understand it better!